# trouble adding place through google places api

Tags: xml, coldfusion, google-places-api

I am trying to add places to google maps using the google places api through coldfusion, I have enabled places in the API settings and am using the correct key as I am able to search for places within a 100 meter radius.

When I try to add a place I get 'INVALID_REQUEST' in the return statement.

Code is as follows:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="variables.addString">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <PlaceAddRequest>
      <location>
          <lat><cfoutput>#variables.lat#</cfoutput></lat>
          <lng><cfoutput>#variables.lng#</cfoutput></lng>
      </location>
      <accuracy>20</accuracy>
      <name><cfoutput>#variables.placeName#</cfoutput></name>
  </PlaceAddRequest>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfhttp
    url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/xml?sensor=false&key=#variables.googlekey#'
    method="POST"
    useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#"
    result="objGet"
>

<cfhttpparam
    type="XML"
    value="#Trim(variables.addString)#"
/>
</cfhttp>
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Without digging too deeply, I can see already that your response (variables.addString) isn't XML-compliant, as it does not start with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. Might not be the issue, but its definitely a start...

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I fixed the xml but the problem persists. I have updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

What is `variables.addString.Trim()`?  Do you mean `trim(variables.addString)`

Comment: Yeah that was a copy paste error.  I fixed it but I am still getting invalid request.

Answer (score 0):

The types parameter is missing. It's a required parameter, even though its not documented as such in the [reference docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#adding_a_place). I've filed a bug to have the document fixed. Hope that helps.